# npm install --legacy-peer-deps - command failed

Tags: python, node.js, npm

In order to try to resolve an issue with node-sass peer dependencies, I tried running the following

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

However when I run this, I get the following stacktrace and I'm not sure what it means

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.15.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:208:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/apple/Documents/projects/nova-web/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2023-03-14T13_09_24_326Z-debug-0.log
```

I have python3 installed but python2 and python are not path variables. Do I need to set ptyhon as a path variable to point to python3?

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, I would suggest that if you are using the Node version that is very recent, then try downgrading and use the stable version `14.16.1`.